# If conditional in Python not providing correct result

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, matplotlib

This is a bit of a strange issue for me and I wasn't sure how to properly title the question. I have the follow MWE which simply generates a list of coordinate points `(x,t)` and performs some check to see if they lie on a user-prescribed boundary. In particular, if `x[i] == 1.0` and `t[i] != 0.0` then the program should print a statement stating so. I can't seem to figure out why the `if` conditional is never entered here. I have printed out the pairs of values `x[i]` and `t[i]` to verify that there are indeed pairs satisfying the conditional...

```
#Load Modules
import numpy as np
import math, random
from pylab import meshgrid

# Create the arrays x and t on an evenly spaced cartesian grid
N = 10
xa = -1.0;
xb = 1.0;

ta = 0.0;
tb = 0.4;

xin = np.arange(xa, xb+0.00001, (xb-xa)/N).reshape((N+1,1))
tin = np.arange(ta, tb+0.00001, (tb-ta)/N).reshape((N+1,1))

X_tmp,T_tmp = meshgrid(xin,tin)
x = np.reshape(X_tmp,((N+1)**2,1))
t = np.reshape(T_tmp,((N+1)**2,1))

# create boundary flags
for i in range(0,(N+1)**2):
    if (x[i] == xb and t[i] != ta):
        print("We are on the right-side boundary")
```

Comment: which python version you use ?

Comment: @mooga Python 3.6 (I am on Mac OS X and my program needs to be integrated with tensorflow, which only works with 3.6 on my computer)

Comment: When I run your code and print out the values I never get an `x[i]` that is equal to 1.0. I get a lot of -1.0s but no positive ones.

Comment: I think it is a floating point error. I am getting a lot of 0.999999999999 for `x[i]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're running into floating point precision issues. So while `x[i]` is very near, it is not exactly equal to `xb`. Perfect equality tests cause trouble like this with floating-point numbers. What you want is to test that the difference between these values is small. Try this:

```
ep = 1e-5 # choose this value based on how close you decide is reasonable
for i in range(0,(N+1)**2):
    if (abs(x[i] - xb) < ep and abs(t[i] - ta) > ep):
       print("We are on the right-side boundary")
```

Also I just learned Python 3.5 added `isclose` functions useful for such cases!
See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024979/333308) for more discussion. Also note that if you want to do this for an array, NumPy provides the [`allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) function.

Comment: Classical IEEE754 pitfall ^^

Comment: This was it, thanks!